# Number of Ways to Draw a Pair in a Poker Deck

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, poker

I am confused over calculating the number of ways in which I can select a pair out of a deck of 52 cards. This is how I go about solving the problem:

Following the definition of a pair in card games, its like 2 cards having the same ranks for instance two 6's or two Aces etc. Hence I can select a first card out of the 52 cards in $C(52,1) = 52$ ways and now that I have selected this card, I only have 3 other cards to select my 2nd card which will be of a different suit but of the same rank so $C(3,1)$ ways to select this card, hence the total number of ways is $52*3 = 156$, but according to this link - [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180217175037/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56158.html) looking at solution (4) I am not able to get why is this such a huge number. Can someone explain it succinctly where am I going wrong?

Comment: In that problem, five cards are selected. The number of such hands with exactly one pair is computed. (Your solution, assuming only two cards are selected, overcounts by a factor of $2$.)

Comment: check out the solution for problem (4) on the link, also what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you choose only two cards, the number of ways of obtaining a pair is $156/2$ (you computed permutations). If a standard five-card poker hand is selected, you need to choose three other cards.

Comment: You should change the title of the question to "getting **at least** a pair, when **picking 5 cards** out 52". The question in the provided link says "In a standard deck of cards, how many different ways are there for getting a straight, a flush, a straight flush, one pair, or two pairs?".

Comment: No I just want to select a pair that is it, okk so the number of permutations is 156, thanks for correcting my solution @David :) I learnt that now.

Comment: @DavidMitra : I also wanted to ask how would we solve questions like this "How many ways are there to select 3 aces and a pair" and other flavors thereof?

Answer (score 3):

First, to clarify the problem, we are drawing two cards and hoping for a pair. The discussion at the link posted in the question is about drawing five cards and hoping for a pair.

There are two counting strategies floating around this page.

One strategy is to first choose any card from the available fifty-two cards. (Perhaps you draw A$\spadesuit$.) Regardless of your draw, there remain in the deck exactly three cards that will complete your first card to a pair. (For example, A$\clubsuit$, A$\heartsuit$, and A$\diamondsuit$.) This strategy counts every pair twice, however. (We wouldn't consider A$\spadesuit$ A$\heartsuit$ as a different hand than A$\heartsuit$ A$\spadesuit$.) We can correct this error by dividing by two, which gives us a final count of $\frac{52 \cdot 3}{2} = 78$.

We can avoid the overcounting and subsequent correction with a different strategy that describes the properties of a pair rather than draws the cards. Every pair is uniquely identified by its rank and two distinct suits of that rank. We first choose one of the thirteen ranks. (Perhaps we choose Ace.) Next, we need two of the four suits of that particular rank (such as $\spadesuit$ and $\heartsuit$) in such a way that order does not matter. This can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways (or $C(4,2)$, if that notation is more familiar). This gives us a total count of $13 \cdot \binom{4}{2} = 78$.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to proceed is the following: there are $C(52,2)$ possible pairs of cards that can be taken out from the deck. The number of pairs in which the two cards have the same rank is $C(4,2)\times 13$. So the probability of taking two cards from the deck and getting a pair of cards with the same rank is $(C(4,2)\times 13)/C(52,2)$.

Comment: The original question does not ask for probability.